# jQuery mobile transition conflict Jquery?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery, conflict, document-ready

I'm working on one site currently:
http://dlt.tribehosting.com/solution

now when I click on Commercial or Residential button it works ok, but when you go to Service page the "toggle" in jQuery just won't work - actually all jQuery script just stop working (same for slider on homepage).

If page is actually reloaded than all is good until user goes to another link and than everything breaks. Is that something to do with (document).ready function as I am using that (you can see in headers).

Any ideas how to prevent this conflicts or to force jQuery toggle to work on all pages when visited via navigation links ??

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `jQuery` instead of `$`?

Comment: not really sure what you mean ?

Comment: `$` is an alias for `jQuery`, if you change $ to jQuery in your script, it should not conflict anymore, if that is indeed the cause.

Comment: tried it and it's not working... :( ...so there must be some other reason why it's now running jQuery scripts :(

Comment: I see that you're using jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 which only supports up to jQuery Core 1.7.1. That probably isn't your problem but you may want to change core files. http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/04/13/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using `document.ready` to run code for pages that are brought-into the DOM via AJAX. Which means that if you want to bind to an event for each page being added to the DOM you should use either `pageinit` or `pagecreate`.

Change:

```
$(function(){
    var sidebar = $('.hor-nav');
    sidebar.delegate('a.inactive','click',function(){
        sidebar.find('.active').toggleClass('active inactive');
        $(this).toggleClass('active inactive');
    });
});
```

To:

```
//run this code when a pseudo-page is added to the DOM
$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pageinit', function(){

    //only get the .hor-nav elements in this pseudo-page
    var $sidebar = $(this).find('.hor-nav');

    //no need to delegate here since the elements for this page exist in the DOM now
    $sidebar.find('a').bind('click',function(){
        $sidebar.find('.active').toggleClass('active inactive');
        $(this).toggleClass('active inactive');
    });
});
```

This will use event delegation on an element that will always exist in the DOM (`document`), whereas the `.hor-nav` elements do not always exist in the DOM if they are a part of an external page.

It looks like you have other code that depends on the `document.ready` event, which should not be the case for a jQuery Mobile website. Take a look at this documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html (notice the large yellow warnings)

Comment: Indeed... I've moved all code depending out of documentready so now it works ! thanks a lot for help !

Comment: Actually there is another strange thing now. if you go to the page: http://lb.vg/Sq684 and click on on Commercial it does apply class active, but when you click back to Residential - it's switching the classes ? Any ideas why ?

Comment: The `a.inactive` selector should be updated to `a` so that all the links are bound to. I've updated my response to reflect this. The `a.inactive` selection is only binding to the currently inactive link, not all of them. You can test this fact by going to any section of your site and clicking on an inactive link, then click on the first link again, notice the classes don't change.